# Switching from https to http

Tags: https

Is it correct to switch from HTTPS to HTTP (say by clicking a click which has full path in the href - with HTTP). Appreciate if someone let know what are the implications in such cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually *can* be a security risk, it depends on your situation.

If you create a session in that HTTPS part, and then visit a HTTP page of the same domain, the session cookie will be sent along with the unsecure HTTP request (plaintext). This makes your site vulnerable to session hijacking, an attacker can use this session id and has the same privileges as the logged in user has.

In PHP you can prevent this behaviour, calling the `session_set_cookie_params()` function, setting the `$secure` parameter to true. This tells the browser, to send the cookie to HTTPS pages only.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will load a page from a non SSL source. No real implications as far as security is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from HTTPS to HTTP is entirely correct if that is what the link is intended to do.

Implications include losing the encrypted communication link between client and server that HTTPS provides.

Answer (score 0):

ssl encryption for the http (s) is used to protect transmitted information. For example, use https on the lognin page. After logging on, you can redirect to http.
So switching https and http is quite all right.